# Content filtering and pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination

I have many div elements separated in three pages using pure JS pagination. This way, the div elements are limited to four per page. Now, I am trying to include a content filter using plain css. It works fine, but you have to go to the next page and see what is filtered there. And the next page, and the next page... How can I make all the divs collapse underneath eachother when filtered, but still to be limited at 4 per page?

```js
var pageList = new Array();
var currentPage = 1;
var numberPerPage = 4;

var events = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".events-section__main-event"));

function getNumberOfPages() {
  return Math.ceil(events.length / numberPerPage);
}

function nextPage() {
  currentPage += 1;
  loadList();
}

function previousPage() {
  currentPage -= 1;
  loadList();
}

function firstPage() {
  currentPage = 1;
  loadList();
}

function lastPage() {
  currentPage = numberOfPages;
  loadList();
}

function loadList() {
  var begin = ((currentPage - 1) * numberPerPage);
  var end = begin + numberPerPage;
  for (i = 0; i < pageList.length; i++) {
    pageList[i].classList.add("not-visible"); // make the old list invisible
  }
  pageList = events.slice(begin, end);
  drawList();
  check();
}

function drawList() {
  for (i = 0; i < pageList.length; i++) {
    pageList[i].classList.remove("not-visible");
  }
}

function check() {
  document.getElementById("next").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("previous").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("first").disabled = currentPage == 1 ? true : false;
  document.getElementById("last").disabled = currentPage == numberOfPages ? true : false;
}

function load() {
  loadList();
}

var numberOfPages = getNumberOfPages();
window.onload = load;
```

```css
#blue:checked~ :not(.blue) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="blue" class="filter-input" name="filter" /><label for="blue" class="filter-label" onclick>Blue</label>

<div id="12" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="11" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="10" class="events-section__main-event"></div>
<div id="9" class="events-section__main-event"></div>
<div id="8" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="7" class="events-section__main-event"></div>
<div id="6" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="5" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="4" class="events-section__main-event"></div>
<div id="3" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
<div id="2" class="events-section__main-event"></div>
<div id="1" class="events-section__main-event blue"></div>
```

Comment: can you make question more clear

Comment: @SamuelJMathew I want to add filtering option to my paginated list of divs. I tried it with css, but the divs are not stacked underneath eachother after filtering. How to include filtering in this pagination?